# Giving control back to the browser in a recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the following recursive scenario within my code where the recursive function is getting called from within a for loop:

```
var recursiveFn = function(node, handlers) {
    ....


     for (i = node.firstChild; i; i = recursiveFn(i, handlers)) {}
     return node.nextSibling;
     ...
};


for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++){
    recursiveFn(node.childNodes[i], true);
}
```

This code is often resulting in slow performance on IE and sometimes IE long running script issue.

What would be the best way to give control back to browser and avoid this error ? I was thinking of the following approach with a counter that would keep track of the number of times the recursion function has run and then give the browser a break after say, 100 iterations:

```
var cnt = 0;
var recursiveFn = function(node, handlers) {
    cnt++; 
    ....


     for (i = node.firstChild; ; ;) {         
         if (cnt >=100) { // If recursive function has run 100 times , give breather to browser
            setTimeout(function(){i = recursiveFn(i,handlers)}, 100); 
         }else {
            i = recursiveFn(i, handlers);
         }   
     }
     return node.nextSibling;
     ...
};


for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++){
    recursiveFn(node.childNodes[i], true);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's sounds fine - only that your function cannot really `return` anything any more when it is asynchronous.

Comment: But wouldn't the stack be maintained ? The thing is the function must return a dom node as a return value

Comment: You would need to make sure all of the callers handle the new method asynchronously.

Comment: Using 0 or 1 milisecond on timeout usually performs better

Comment: No, it wouldn't be maintained - that's why I said that you cannot use `return` any more. You will need to use a callback instead. However, without showing us what that function *exactly* does, we can't really show you the solution.

Comment: The only place this function gets called is the for loop at the bottom and ofcourse from within the function itself.

Comment: I think that the **first** thing you should do is make sure that there's not something (very) inefficient about your code that's making the script take that long. Old versions of IE had slow JavaScript runtimes, but they weren't *that* slow.  Before you go to some elaborate time-slice architecture, do some profiling in a modern browser and see if there aren't ways to improve the code.

Comment: Here is the code : http://pastebin.com/bFABfFAW

Comment: In that code it doesn't seem like you're doing anything with the response from the `recurse` function?

Comment: There is no response as such, its simply recursing through the dom tree and processing nodes. It returns a sibling node in some cases just to keep the recursion going.